# Why are my custom wire bone shapes' lines thicker when in Pose Mode?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, pose-mode

The wire bones on the right are thicker than they should be. In my other blend files the custom wire bones are like the left picture when in pose mode. I have tried almost every setting that I can think of, but I can't get this fixed. It seems like the wireframe display lines are 3-4 pixels thick instead of 1 or whatever the default is. This is pretty annoying visually and makes the rig look less clean. I feel like this is a bug or else I have activated some obscure option or hotkey.

[image: Left is correct, right is incorrect]

Comment: Probably to help show selection and to differentiate between armatures that are not selected/connected

Comment: It was not enabled in a previous autosave of the same blend file and in my other projects the wire frames all display correctly in pose mode. I'm trying to figure out how to turn it off. I guess I should have worded my question differently.I meant to find out which setting is causing this.